# How to change width of a datatable column filter (calendar)?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with css class. I changed width with inspect element easily but I can't change it via style.css. Which class should I use?

[datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3AkE.png)

[inspect element code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0bxv.jpg)

Code:

```
<p:column id="dateFrom"  headerText="DATUM OD"
            filterBy="#{log.datumOd}" sortBy="#{log.datum_upisa}">
            <f:facet   name="filter">

                <p:calendar  onkeyup="PF('loggerTable').filter()"
                    onchange="PF('loggerTable').filter()" id="from"
                    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" widgetVar="dateFrom">
                    <p:ajax  event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('loggerTable').filter()"
                        update="logsTable" />
                </p:calendar>

            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="datumOdZaBrisanje" value="#{log.datum_upisa}" />
</p:column>
```

Edited: [css edited with browser developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXee5.jpg)

I want to set width: 95px. I have tried filterStyle, class, wrap it with a div, but nothing happens

Comment: can you get it to work using a browser developer tool and hack some css in there? Yes you can... Why did you not post that?

Comment: Post edited now, please check third image, ty

Comment: code in text please, not images.... this is with INLINE style on a very low level component. Try with a class on a parent of grandparent and the right css

Comment: Done! Class on a parent works. .parentClass input{ width: 95px }

Answer (score -3):

**use it**,
inside your style.css file in write `width: 95px !important;`

Comment: 1: Selector is missing. Answer is sort of useless then. 2: See the last topic before the see also in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles !important should be the very, very last resort. OP can get this easily working with a good selector.